# Page is not scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm a complete `css` noob and not sure what's going on. The form on the page I'm creating is being cut off at the bottom of the screen, however the user has no ability to scroll down to see the rest of the content.

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="nav-wrapper">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" id="search">Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="createCode">Create PENSGC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="displayX">Display Exceptions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="createX">Create Exception</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="render-body">
                @RenderBody()                  
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    background-image: url("/Images/Swiftnet-Background.jpg");
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#render-body {
    height: auto;
}

#content {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white; 
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px 10px / 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
    box-shadow: -3px 10px 62px -18px rgba(10,9,10,0.75);
}

/*#body {
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}*/

a:link, a:visited,
a:active, a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #c7d1d6;
}

header, footer, hgroup, section {
    display: block;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */
nav {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*remove indent*/
ul {
    margin-left: -25px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}



/* forms */
.display-label, 
.editor-label {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.editor-box-label 
{
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #696969;
}

.display-field, 
.editor-field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
    color: Black;
}

fieldset {
    border: 2px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

fieldset legend {
    text-align: center;
}

fieldset ol {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

fieldset ol li {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

label.checkbox {
    display: inline;
}

input, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 5px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 300px;
}

textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    width: 500px;
}

    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        border: 1px solid #7ac0da;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"] {
        background: transparent;
        border: inherit;
        width: auto;
    }

    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="button"],
    button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }

    td input[type="submit"],
    td input[type="button"],
    td button {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }

/* info and errors */
.message-info {
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.message-error {
    clear: both;
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.message-success {
    color: #7ac0da;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.error {
    color: #e80c4d;
}

/* styles for validation helpers */
.field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}

input[type="checkbox"].input-validation-error {
    border: 0 none;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    color: #e80c4d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

/* tables
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 0.75em;
    border: 0 none;
}

th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    border: none 0px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

    th a {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }

    th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    th a:hover {
        color: #000;
    }

    th.asc a, th.desc a {
        margin-right: .75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after, th.desc a:after {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0em;
        top: 0;
        font-size: 0.75em;
    }

    th.asc a:after {
        content: '▲';
    }

    th.desc a:after {
        content: '▼';
    }

td {
    padding: 0.25em 2em 0.25em 0em;
    border: 0 none;
}

tr.pager td {
    padding: 0 0.25em 0 0;
}

/* footer
----------------------------------------------------------*/
footer .float-left,
footer .float-right {
    float: none;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

    footer p {
        margin: 0;
    }

.form-container {
   clear: both;
   overflow: auto;
}

.form-panel-inner {
   width:auto;
   float:left;
   padding-right: 20px;
   padding-left: 20px;
}
```

**View**

```
@model PENSGC_Generator.Models.PENSGC
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#search').click(function() {

        });
        $('#createCode').click(function() {

        });
        $('#displayX').click(function() {

        });
        $('#createX').click(function() {

        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="BigDiv" class="form-container">          
        <div id="LeftDiv" class="form-panel-inner">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Search Criteria</legend>
                <table id="searchTable" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OriginalStatNum)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OriginalStatNum, new { style = "width:80px;" })
                            </div>             
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportsToStat)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReportsToStat, new { style = "width:80px;" })
                            </div>                
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OriginalMarketSegment)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OriginalMarketSegment, new { style = "width:80px;" })
                            </div>                          
                        </td>                    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pensgc)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pensgc, new { style = "width:80px;" })
                            </div>                         
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OriginalName)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-label" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OriginalName, new { style = "width:160px;" })
                            </div>                       
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OriginalEffectiveDate)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OriginalEffectiveDate)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OriginalCancelDate)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OriginalCancelDate)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ExceptionName)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExceptionName, Model.ExcpetionListDropDown, " ")
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastUpdateId)
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastUpdateId, new { style="width: 80px;", @readonly="readonly" })
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="RightDiv" class="form-panel-inner">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>DSS Distributor Info</legend>
                <table style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AgencyName)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AgencyName, new { @readonly="readonly"})
                            </div>                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyCode)
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyCode, new { style="width:80px;", @readonly="readonly"})
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecSellerCd)                            
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SecSellerCd, new { style="width:80px;", @readonly="readonly"})
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OriginalMarketSegment)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OriginalMarketSegment, new { style="width:80px;", @readonly="readonly"})
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LifeAnn)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LifeAnn, new { style="width:80px;", @readonly="readonly"})
                            </div>                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConnCode)  
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConnCode, new { style="width:80px;", @readonly="readonly"})
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CancelRsn, new { style="width:80px;", @readonly="readonly"})
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CancelRsn, new { style="width:80px;", @readonly="readonly"})
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportsToAgn)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReportsToAgn)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                @*Relationship Codes read from Dictionary object*@
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <th>Relationship Code</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.RelCodes)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.Display(item.Key) 
                                    @Html.Display("121")
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.Display(item.Value)
                                    @Html.Display("Channel Desc")
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }                       
                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>              
}
```

**EDIT**

Per request here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33Wex/

Comment: Can you please add a JSFiddle

Comment: It is related to `position: fixed`. The object with this property usually behaves in strange ways, in your case everything is in a `position: fixed` div, so your entire site is broken. I'm pretty sure you can find a better way of centering your content.

Answer (score 0):

Try  changing your container div to be like this:

```
<div id="BigDiv" class="form-container">
```

Add this CSS:

```
.form-container {
   clear: both;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Also, optimize your CSS like this:

```
 <div id="LeftDiv" class="form-panel-inner">
 <div id="RightDiv" class="form-panel-inner">

.form-panel-inner {
   width:auto;
   float:left;
   padding-right: 20px;
   padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimization tip. The page is still not scrolling, however.

Answer (score 0):

This will be due to you fixing the content so that it remains in the same position

```
display: block;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -300px;
margin-left: -400px;
```

if you are trying to center the content I would remove these lines and replace with

```
margin:0px auto 0px auto; 
width:xxxpx;
```

replace the first 0px in the margin with whatever margin you require from the top (goes clockwise, top right, bottom, left) and also give the content a width so the auto can work out what it needs to be.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your goal is, but I adjusted your fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/33Wex/2/)

Replaced:

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -300px;
margin-left: -400px;
```

With:

```
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
position: relative;
```

And achieved a similar effect.

Comment: This fixes the scrolling issue, but now the width is basically the entire size of the browser. I adjusted the `width` to `auto` for both the `render-body` and `content` divs but no luck. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want it to look like?  Are you wanting a gap to give the page a hover-type look where you can see the shadow on both sides?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by changing the `position` attribute to `absolute`. The following css values centered the `content` div element in the page and allowed for the page to scroll.

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -350px;
    margin-left: -400px;
```